# Convert String dd/MM/yyyy date into java.sql.date yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: mysql, date, servlets

I am using the below method to do the described conversion. But the `java.sql.Date` method is deprecated. So, is their any harm in using this method? As the statements below are working fine.

### (Retrieving value of date as string in servlet from session and then storing the date in MySQL.)

```
String f33_ = (String) session.getAttribute("sf33");
```

---

```
java.sql.Date f33 = new java.sql.Date(Integer.parseInt(f33_.substring(6, 10))- 1900, Integer.parseInt(f33_.substring(3, 5))-1,Integer.parseInt(f33_.substring(0, 2)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` (or the equivalent from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)) rather than trying to parse this yourself:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

java.util.Date date = format.parse(text);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.. Actually i was confused with the usage of getTime() function because their is no need of time here, only date is required. And is their any harm in using deprecated method?

Comment: One more thing, what is the need of setting time zone?

Comment: DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

java.util.Date date = format.parse(text);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
this code is also working. any difference with your code?

Comment: @user1255357: If you don't set the time zone, it will treat it as midnight *in that time zone* - which may then end up as a different day in the database. And yes, you shouldn't use the deprecated methods of `Date` - did I accidentally use one? (Hope not...)

Comment: @user1255357: Yes - it will use the system default time zone, which may give you different results, and use the system default locale, which may use a different calendar system. (I thought it would affect the `/` too, but apparently it doesn't. I'm not *sure* whether the calendar system is defaulted from the locale, but I'd expect it to be.)

Comment: so mine would work fine with a server. because mine reduced coding would use server default time zone and time. right?

Comment: @user1255357: No - because the server time zone may not be what you want. I *strongly* suspect you want to use UTC and a US locale. You need to find out how your database is going to handle the date - I *suspect* it will assume it's in UTC. (A `Date` is actually just an instant in time, with no time zone or calendar indication.)

Comment: Great! your point is totally valid. some time server time is also changed due to security reasons, this can also affect date entry in database. Thanks for clearing all doubts.