# Change String values in List<String> to java.sql.date values to insert into SQL DB

Tags: java, sql, date, arraylist, jdbc

I have a `List` of `String` values that contains the date in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

I am currently trying to iterate through the list to add the individual values to the DB.

How do I convert the individual `String` values in the `String` List to `java.sql.Date` values in order for them to match the data type contained in the database?

Below is an example of the code I am using:

```
    List<String> accessedDate = usageEvent.getDate();
    List<Integer> totlUsageHits = usageEvent.getHits();
    List<Integer> totlUsageVisitors = usageEvent.getVisitors(); 

    Iterator<String> accessDate = accessedDate.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> hits = totlUsageHits.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> visitors = totlUsageVisitors.iterator();

    while (accessDate.hasNext() && hits.hasNext() && visitors.hasNext()) {
            insert.setDate(1, accessDate.next());
            insert.setInt(2, hits.next());
            insert.setInt(3, visitors.next());
            insert.addBatch();
    }
```

Where I have `insert.setDate(1, accessDate.next());`, I want to change the `String` values from this list to `java.sql.Date` values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624777/convert-string-dd-mm-yyyy-date-into-java-sql-date-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: your question is "How to convert String to java.sql.date" :)

Comment: How do I implement this is relation to my above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JDBC driver serves as a bridge adapter between the types/data in your Java code, and the actual statement which will run on your SQL database.  One approach here would be to convert your text Java dates to `LocalDate`, and then bind them to the statement as objects:

```
while (accessDate.hasNext() && hits.hasNext() && visitors.hasNext()) {
    String date = accessDate.next();
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    insert.setObject(1, localDate);
    insert.setInt(2, hits.next());
    insert.setInt(3, visitors.next());
    insert.addBatch();
}
```

A JDBC 4.2 driver should know how to deal with a Java `LocalDate` object.  You might have actually been OK with the text dates, because there are in an ISO format, but it is better to avoid working with string dates, both in Java and SQL.